# How to handle stage specific keystore in docker images

Tags: docker, keystore

I have the situation that I have **multiple stages** with **different certificates** for encryption. As a best practice docker containers are immutable between stages, and only parameterized via environment variables. This would allow to use a stage specific keystore password but would not allow for putting a new certificate in the image.

I thought of the following option:

- A stage specific docker image / build
- Loading the keystore over the network on container startup (giving url and password as environment variables)
- The keystore on a docker data volume.

Anyone made experience with this situation and can share his best practices? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

> Loading the keystore over the network on container startup (giving url and password as environment variables)

Actually, for storing and accessing secrets (like passwords), you could setup a dedicated container using [**`hashicorp/vault`**](https://github.com/hashicorp/vault) ([`vaultproject.io`](https://www.vaultproject.io/)).

You have a [full tutorial on KataCoda](https://www.katacoda.com/courses/docker-production/vault-secrets) mentioned by [Ben Hall](https://github.com/BenHall) (creator of KataCoda) in [issue 165](https://github.com/hashicorp/vault/issues/165#issuecomment-228419704), or an example with [`sjourdan/docker-vault`](https://github.com/sjourdan/docker-vault).